# Use of undeclared identifier "UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight" iOS 8.2?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I used code

```
 UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                            message:message
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[alertView setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
[alertView show];
```

i am getting error for Unused identifier at line

```
[alertView setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
```

It work for iOS 9 fine but not on iOS 8.2.How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Hi , semanticContentAttribute property is available from ios 9.0 only , you need to check os version or try like this

```
if ([alertView respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(setSemanticContentAttribute:)]) {
   [alertView setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3] forKey:@"semanticContentAttribute"];
}
```

Comment: it is used to text alignment left to right , or right to left

Comment: generally we read english from left to right , but some other languages are read right to left in that case we need to use this property

Comment: for more information refer https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages.html